# ¿Cómo podría solucionar un problema de duplicidad de atributos de varias clases en Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Buenas noches tengo un problema relacionado con SonarCloud, me indica que hay duplicación de líneas de código, revisando veo que son DTO's que tienen en su mayoría anotaciones de Lombok, revisando el tema pensaba que con la herencia se podría solucionar pero creo que al final seguirían habiendo duplicaciones.

Esto es un experimento mental que intentaba hacer que sucedía:

```
clase base { campo 1}
clase base_2 { campo 3, campo 4, campo 5}
clase base_3 extends base { campo 2}

clase 1 extends base {}

clase 2 extends base_3 {}

clase 3 extends base_2 {
campo 2
}

clase 4 extends base_2 { }
```

Pero en este caso creo que se generaría duplicaciones en las clases base y no se solucionaría el problema.

¿Hay una manera de abordar esto de una mejor manera, teniendo en cuenta que la cantidad de atributos varía en cada clase?